# Ruby, one line guard clause with return value

Tags: ruby

I have ruby code that does the following

```rb
return [:error, "error message"] if guard_clause_fails?
```

What I would like to write is something like this

```rb
return (insert 2nd part of guard_clause_fails?) if guard_clause_fails?

def guard_clause_fails?
  return [false, [:error, "error message"]]
end
```

Is there a nice readable idiomatic way to write this in ruby? *in one line*

I could do

```rb
def guard_clause_fails?
  @_return_code = [:error, "error message"]
  false
end

return @_return_code if @guard_clause_fails?
```

I want more self documenting code rather than having the next developer wonder what @_return_code is.

Comment: What's wrong with `return [:error, "error message"] if guard_clause_fails?`?

Comment: This is really `if (objection = guard_clause_test); return objection; end`, where that could be generalized to where the clauses could be an array and you return either the first, or all objections.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like when methods return different types and the calling method need to guess by the response if an error happened or if the response is the result of a successful method call.

Instead, I would consider returning a value object. Imagine this module:

```
module ValueResponse
  Response = Data.define(:success?, error: nil, value: nil)

  def error(error)
    Response.new(false, error:)
  end

  def success(value)
    Response.new(true, value:)
  end
end
```

Include that module into the class in question and use it like this:

```
include ValueResponse

def example_method
  return error('message') if guard_clause_fails?

  # ...
  success(actual_return_value)
end
```

Then it is clear to the caller of the method what the response of the method actually means.

```
response = example_method

if response.success?
  response.value   # read success response
else
  response.error   # handle error message
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could conditionally `yield` the return code from the method:

```
def guard_clause_fails?
  yield [:error, "error message"] if @error_condition
end
```

This allows you to return it from within the block, e.g.:

```
def foo
  guard_clause_fails? { |code| return code }

  [:success]
end

@error_condition = true
foo #=> [:error, "error message"]

@error_condition = false
foo #=> [:success]
```

---

[`catch`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-catch) and [`throw`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) might also be an option: (the `!` is just for decoration purposes)

```
def guard_clause_fails!
  throw :abort, [:error, "error message"] if @condition
end

def foo
  catch(:abort) do
    guard_clause_fails!

    [:success]
  end
end

@condition = true
foo #=> [:error, "error message"]

@condition = false
foo #=> [:success]
```

Comment: this would be interesting when  "it" is put into ruby 3.4?   {  return it }

Comment: @Daniel totally missed that one! So after 13 years they finally implemented [#4475](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4475) the way it was intended ;)